# Positioning independently of axes in groupplots with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

Is it possible to indicate the position of a node in an `axis` or `groupplot` environment as a ratio? For example `\mynode{.5,.5}{$A$}` would place `$A$` in the center of the axes, for any `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax`.

That would be particularly convenient with `groupplots`, if I wanted to add a label on the top right of each graph, the graphs having different scales, for example.

MWE showing that $A$ and $B$ do not have the same position, because the axes have different scales and origins:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                      group name=myplot,
                      group size= 2 by 4},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-2,xmax=3,ymin=-2,ymax=6]
                \node at (axis cs:0.,0.) {$A$}; % line of interest         
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-50,xmax=100,ymin=-100,ymax=50]
                \node at (axis cs:0.,0.) {$B$}; % line of interest
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The "lines of interest" of the code should be changed to something like `\mynode at (relative:0.2,0.2) {$A$}` (or other syntaxes of course) to place the node at 20%, 20% from the lower left corner.

Comment: use `rel axis cs:` or `axis description cs:` instead of `axis cs:` to accomplish that. (As long as you don't use a "reversed" axis they both behave the same.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already stated in the comments, here are the two possibilities shown in a bit adapted MWE.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group name=myplot,
                group size= 2 by 4,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=6.4cm,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-2,xmax=3,ymin=-2,ymax=6]
            % you have two choices to place stuff "relatively" in the plot
            % which yield the same result on "normal" axis
            \node at (axis description cs:0.2,0.2) {$A$};
            \node at (rel axis cs:0.2,0.8) {$a$};
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-50,xmax=100,ymin=-100,ymax=50,
            % but if you reverse the axis, the behavior can be adapted,
            % depending on the value of `allow reversal of rel axis cs'
            x dir=reverse,
            allow reversal of rel axis cs=false,
        ]
            \node at (axis description cs:0.2,0.2) {$B$};
            \node at (rel axis cs:0.2,0.8) {$b$};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]